# QGIS 3 : Produce classification on field where multiple values can be stored (comma separated value)

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, lizmap

To explain what I want to do the best is a simple example.
I have a layer with point for audio geolocated notes. The attribute "type" can store different values : "problem", "surface", "question", "to_osm" or combination of these values.

Now to do style the layer in QGIS I use a rule for each type :  `"type" ILIKE '%problem%'`.

After I have created each rules I could interact with notes and choose to see, only one or multiple types.
[image]

This solution work well for me since more than 2 years. It is a DIY patch that take time to do and could be easily broken (rename column). I think that this problem was common on GIS data representation.

Yesterday i have found out that solution to build style direct from data exist. With the Lizmap (a webgis solution based on QGIS server), the form filtering feature you are able to set a separator for a field containing multiple unique values. [LINK](https://docs.lizmap.com/current/fr/publish/lizmap_plugin/form_filtering.html#unique-values) and extract :

> If you have specified a splitter text, for example `,` , Lizmap will find the unique values of the separated text values. For example the value of one feature `culture, environment` will be split into `culture` and `environment` with the splitter `,` . Selecting `culture` or `environment` in the form input will show this feature.

I am asking is there a better solution to do classification of a field with multiple values based on QGIS styling rules ?

---

PS : I have tried also other solutions based on data structure modification (i use it sometimes) :

- create a column for each type and fill it with boolean : hard to maintain the styling and edit data
- create relation n to n : hard to make it work and then share it with others
- duplicate features for each types : hard to edit the rest of the data

Comment: I don't clearly see the backdraws of your current symbology nor i see the benefit of splitting your 'type' attributes ... i'm not sure you can ever think of a symbology that would **not** be dependent of your table structure and naming ...

Comment: Hello, the backdraws are mainly comfort and reproducibility : manual action is needed to build style (there is about 10 to 15 class). I am seeking for clean solution because I know it is handeled on Lizmap.

Comment: Your link refers to Lizmap's form *filter* and the way it scans the attribute table content to *filter* features ... i don't see what could be applied in it to symbology.

Comment: As the filter does the split of column content it could then be feed to the classification styling of QGIS.

Comment: splitting/not splitting is almost not the question : how would u find a logic that is **not** dependent on your data's structure ? since it seems that's what you're seeking.

Comment: You can set your classification styling to study an expression based on a field. I use it often but there is still many option i do not know, may be one for my case... may be not. The goal of my question is not to miss a solution. ; )